# Putting equations next to each other when there's room (i.e. math mode in subfigure)

Tags: equations, positioning, subfloats

I have a group of multiline formulas (with `\begin{split}`) of varying heights and widths in a float and there's a lot of unused horizontal space. I'd like the equations to go next to each other when there's enough space, but `\begin{subfigure}` won't accept math mode.

Comment: It is always best to compose a [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. It will also help to test that the solution provided works for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you are using a floating environment to write your equations. Anyway, to display your equations side by side you could use `minipage`s. Another option would be to use the subsidiary environments `gathered`, `aligned`, and `alignedat` from the `amsmath` package; those environments produce a structure whose total width is the actual width of the contents. The following example illustrates both approaches:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \\
  E = mc^2. \\
  x^n + y^n = z^n.
\end{gather*}

\noindent\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \\
  E = mc^2. \\
  x^n + y^n = z^n.
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.5\textwidth}
\begin{gather*}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \\
  E = mc^2. \\
  x^n + y^n = z^n.
\end{gather*}
\end{minipage}%

\begin{equation*}
\begin{gathered}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \\
  E = mc^2. \\
  x^n + y^n = z^n.
\end{gathered}\hspace{6em}
\begin{gathered}
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2. \\
  E = mc^2. \\
  x^n + y^n = z^n.
\end{gathered}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! The gathered/aligned approach works inside a float as well.